# Convert DataTable to output suitable for powershell without knowing column names or types c#

Tags: c#, linq, powershell, datatable

I have an api call that returns a DataSet object in C#. All I want to do is return this data from my cmdlet I'm developing back to powershell for use on the pipeline, but I don't really want to have to do this manually, as the underlying API can change dynamically.

All examples of DataSet / DataTable etc are using linq but they always specify the column names - which I don't have the luxury of at design time.

I'm not really sure the best way to go about this as I am not a c# developer - so I don't really know what terminolgy to even search for, so Pointers of how I can return WriteObject(ds.Tables[0]); in a way that can be used in powershell without having to manipulate datatables too would be appreciated.

Thanks

David

EDIT:

Can't get my comment to post properly..

so I've done it like this:

```
PSObject ps = new PSObject();
foreach (DataRow dtRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        ps.Members.Add(new PSNoteProperty(dc.ColumnName, dtRow[dc].ToString()));
    }
}
WriteObject(ps);
```

Comment: with datatable columns you can always use the index [?] instead of names.  You also can extract the names from the columns property foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns).  Then dc.ColumnName .

Comment: For linq, string[] names  = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray();

Comment: Not sure if its the best way to do it, but I have got it working as per the edit to my first post, as I couldn't format this comment correctly.